# Dynamically show specific tab when opening a tabbed activity from notification

Tags: android, tabs, android-notifications

I have a mothod for opening the main Activity when pressing on a notifcation. The Activity to be opened is a Tabbed Activity with three tabs. How can I get it to open tab nr. 2 for example?

Here is my code:

```
private void sendNotification(int antal, String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("NEW_INTENT", true);
    editor.commit();

    // MainActivity will open -> how do I show a specific tab?
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, dk.gis34.borgertip.activity.MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("FORCE_REFRESH", true);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    Notification n = mBuilder.build();
    n.number = antal;
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your pass the activity `Intent` in the `PendingIntent`, add the position of tab to be selected using `putExtras()` and get this value in `onCreate()` method of activity and handle the position of Tab to selected.